# How to avoid using limit query in sql redshift to get last x weeks of data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a query below which gives me data for the past 8 weeks and it works fine -

```
WITH dates
AS (
    SELECT (
            date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE - 7 * (
                row_number() OVER (
                    ORDER BY true
                    ) - 1
                ) - INTERVAL '1 day'
            )::DATE AS week_info
    FROM data.process LIMIT 8
    )
SELECT dates.week_info
    ,'W' || ceiling(date_part('week', dates.week_info + INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_number
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT zeus.client_id) AS PROC
FROM data.active_values zeus
JOIN dates ON zeus.updated_timestamp <= dates.week_info
WHERE zeus.kites_version = (
        SELECT MAX(kites_version)
        FROM data.active_values f2
        WHERE zeus.client_id = f2.client_id
            AND zeus.type = f2.type
            AND f2.updated_timestamp <= dates.week_info
        )
    AND zeus.type = 'hello-world'
    AND zeus.STATUS = 'CURRENT'
GROUP BY dates.week_info
ORDER BY dates.week_info DESC LIMIT 8
```

But the problem I have is I am using `limit 8` to get the above query working. I am trying to see if there is any way by which we can avoid using limit 8 and just use `zeus.updated_timestamp` value to get the past 8 weeks data in a similar output format as my current query is giving?

Output is coming like this from above query and I want it to be in this format only:

```
week_info   week_number   PROC
--------------------------------    
2020-10-25  W44            100
2020-10-18  W43            101
2020-10-11  W42            109
2020-10-04  W41            134
2020-09-27  W40            982
2020-09-20  W39            187
2020-09-13  W38            765 
2020-09-06  W37            234
```

**Note:-**

`updated_timestamp` column has full date in it like `2020-10-28 18:56:25:17`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help -- as would an explanation of what the query should be doing.  You are aggregating by `dates.week_info` which should only have 8 rows, so it is not clear why you need the `limit` in the outer query.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I just updated it. @GordonLinoff

Comment: I am trying to get rid of limit 8 from both the places I have in my query. I think we can just use `zeus.updated_timestamp` to rewrite this query if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 2 removals of LIMIT requested.  The first, in the CTE, can be replaced by adding a WHERE clause in the outer select - "WHERE dates.week_info > 8 weeks ago" (I'll leave it to you to define 8 weeks ago.  Also there are more efficient ways to make 8 dates than using a window function and scanning an unneeded table but that is your choice.  Changing this will remove the LIMIT / WHERE need all together. Your CTE then looks something like:

```
select date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE -  (t.num * 7) - 1 as week_info
from (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7) as t (num)
```

The second LIMIT is coming about because of the inequality in the JOIN clause which is causing a lot of row replication - I hope this is really what you need.  There will only be 8 dates coming from the CTE AND having a GROUP BY on this date means that there will only be 8 rows of output.  If there are only 8 possible rows there is no reason to have a LIMIT.

EDIT - merged code (untested):

```
WITH dates
AS (
    select date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE -  (t.num * 7) - 1 as week_info
from (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7) as t (num)
    )
SELECT dates.week_info
    ,'W' || ceiling(date_part('week', dates.week_info + INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_number
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT zeus.client_id) AS PROC
FROM data.active_values zeus
JOIN dates ON zeus.updated_timestamp <= dates.week_info
WHERE zeus.kites_version = (
        SELECT MAX(kites_version)
        FROM data.active_values f2
        WHERE zeus.client_id = f2.client_id
            AND zeus.type = f2.type
            AND f2.updated_timestamp <= dates.week_info
        )
    AND zeus.type = 'hello-world'
    AND zeus.STATUS = 'CURRENT'
GROUP BY dates.week_info
ORDER BY dates.week_info DESC
```

EDIT 2 - attempt to address correlated subquery issue:

If I understand correctly the where clause in question is just trying to ensure that only client_ids with values that match on kite_version are counted.  A more direct (and less error prone) way to get this is to calculate the subgroup max directly.  The below code attempts to do this but I don't have your data nor your business intent so this is an example of a better way to attack this type of requirement.

```
WITH dates
AS (
    select date_trunc('week', getdate() + INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE -  (t.num * 7) - 1 as week_info
from (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7) as t (num)
    ),
active_values_plus AS (
SELECT client_id, updated_timestamp, type, status, kites_version, MAX(kites_version) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, type) AS max_kites_version
        FROM data.active_values
)
SELECT dates.week_info
    ,'W' || ceiling(date_part('week', dates.week_info + INTERVAL '1 day')) AS week_number
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT zeus.client_id) AS PROC
FROM active_values_plus zeus
JOIN dates ON zeus.updated_timestamp <= dates.week_info
WHERE zeus.kites_version = zeus.max_kites_version
    AND zeus.type = 'hello-world'
    AND zeus.STATUS = 'CURRENT'
GROUP BY dates.week_info
ORDER BY dates.week_info DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think I understood some part but confuse on few things. Where I am suppose to integrate this query in my above code? If possible can you provide an example with my query on how it will look like with your above suggestion? That will help me to understand better.

Comment: The SQL I propose is the entire WITH dates AS ( ... ) contents.  You shouldn't need the LIMIT 8 at the end.  Now I don't have your data to test but works on my contrived example.  I can edit the answer to provide the whole replacement if this isn't clear - just let me know.

Comment: I can test it on my end if you can provide me the whole replacement. Just kinda confuse as of now where your suggestion fits.

Comment: yeah I tried your updated query but I get an error as - `This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error` Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The correlated subquery is "WHERE zeus.kites_version = (SELECT ..." clause.  This is where not having your data / data-model limits what I can determine.  Are client_id and type the primary keys of active_values?  (only one row per unique value pair of the columns)  If so what is "f2.updated_timestamp <= dates.week_info" for?  If not what is being done with the last join?  I suspect that this last join can be replaced with a simpler construct.

Comment: This is legacy query which I am trying to make it dynamic query if possible. We have internal tool built that we use to query redshift tables. I only have read permission as well. I tried checking primary keys on that table but couldn't see it unless I did something wrong. I will try your updated query and see if it works.

Comment: In your updated query what is this `kite_version` column in your `active_values_plus ` line in the sql? Is it `kites_version` column?

Comment: I think writing like this `FROM data.active_values_plus zeus` it doesn't work for me? I mean assigning alias to another alias and then using that later on it doesn't work for me somehow.

Comment: Well I hope I didn't make a typo coming from my test case to matching your tables and columns.  What error message are you getting?  This can be rewritten as a sub-select but your original used CTEs so I went that route.

Comment: yeah I think there is a typo unless I am wrong on `kite_version`. Can you check that out in your updated query? Also are we sure we can write like this - `FROM data.active_values_plus zeus`? Since `active_values_plus` is alias right? and the writing `data.` infront of it? It was complaining as it cannot find `updated_timestamp` column on zeus for some reason.

Comment: Yep, I left off that column from the CTE definition, sorry.  I fixed the code in the answer.

Comment: Yes this syntax/structure is fine.  The WITH clause is defining 2 new things that can be referenced in the top query - "dates" and "active_values_plus".  Active_values_plus is the same data as active_values but with a new column created on the fly.  This new column holds the max kite_version for the the partition.  That active_values_plus is referred to as zeus is just like the original. 
Now barring another oops on my part the new query should run.  Hopefully it  will give the same result as original - I just don't have enough info on the data model to be sure.

Comment: I tried your updated query again but I got an error as I mentioned earlier - `relation "data.active_values_plus" does not exist`. I think using db name on alias doesn't work maybe?

Comment: Yep, another copy paste error.  Fixed in answer.  Just like the error says data.active_values_plus does not exists - needs to be the locally defined CTE active_values_plus which does not exist in the schema "data".

Comment: yeah I have tried that already but I get another error as which I wasn't sure of - `Invalid operation: column zeus.kites_version does not exist;` Any idea why is this error? I removed extra `s` though but still same error.

Comment: kites_version, not kite_version.  Fixed.

Comment: I see it needed to be present in that select query so that means we need to add `type` and `status` as well in the same innersql query. After adding those then it runs fine and I get the data but data is not matching with my original manual query run so trying to see what's wrong.

Comment: If you post some sample data and expected output I can possibly help.  But please post expected business result, not output of the original query, as I have doubts that this is doing what you think it is doing. Too many unneeded inequalities and use of DISTINCT where it really shouldn't be needed.   However, I don't have your data so cannot see what these are doing for you - I just have doubts.